# Google Compute Engine Click-to-Deploy LAMP stack coordinator instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

Why does Google Compute Engine Click-to-Deploy LAMP stack create these 2 instances?

[image]

What is the purpose of the coordinator instance? I already stopped this instance and all continues to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deployment coordinator module is a single, short-lived instance is created during the deployment. This instance exists to ensure that the long-running LAMP server instances can run under the principle of least privilege. This instance will remove itself after your LAMP Stack deployment has been created. For more information about Deployment Coordinator take a look at [Deployment work flow chart of this article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/cassandra/deployment-details) which is valid for LAMP stack as well.

Comment: It's used simply to create the persistent disk volume and attach it to the LAMP instance, without granting the permission to do so to the LAMP instance itself.  Thereby limiting the permissions of the LAMP instance to only what is needed.